# Excel VBA script - InputBox Error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a VBA script so that if somebody types "Size" it will paste "Size" 5 Times, and if they Type "SizeColor" it will paste 5 "SizeColor" cells.

Also if possible if I can get something like, if user inputs anything other than "Size" or "SizeColor" then they will get a message saying they can't do that.

```
Sub SizeAndColor()

Dim val, Size, SizeC As String
Size = "Size"
SizeC = "SizeColor"

val = InputBox("Size or SizeColor?", "Options")

If val = "Size" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 122).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Size
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Size
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Size
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Size
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Size
    ActiveCell.Offset(5, -122).Select

Else: val = "SizeColor"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 122).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = SizeC
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = SizeC
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = SizeC
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = SizeC
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = SizeC
    ActiveCell.Offset(5, -122).Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What issues are you experiencing with the existing code?  Getting any errors?

Comment: Easy part first: Just before 'End Sub', insert 'Else' then msgbox saying they can only enter ___. Do you really mean to go over 122 columns to enter the five values?

Comment: This is going to lead to interesting behavior, imagine you write another script which sets the selected value to a different cell then what you expected. And then this offsets from that over 122 spaces... avoid select if you can.

Comment: Things is I will always use this from the correct cell I have it in my ribbon so I don't accidental hit a key to paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your variables properly. You can't do implicit type assignments in VBA, so:

`Dim val, Size, SizeC As String` actually means:

`Dim Val as Variant, Size as Variant, SizeC As String`.

In any case, you don't need either variable `Size` or `SizeC`, so, let's try this instead :

```
Sub SizeAndColor()

Dim val As String 'Input box value
Dim cl As Range

Set cl = ActiveCell
TryAgain:
val = InputBox("Size or SizeColor?", "Options")

Select Case LCase(val) 'Assuming you don't care about case sensitivity, SIZE = size, etc.
    Case "size", "sizecolor"
       '## Put the values 122 columns to the right, and 5 rows down
        cl.Offset(0, 122).Resize(5, 1).Value = val
        cl.Select
    Case Else
    'Do NOT allow any other inputs:
        If MsgBox("You have entered an invalid input. Please input only 'Size' or 'SizeColor'. Try again?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            GoTo TryAgain
        Else:
            Exit Sub
        End If
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: The GoTo TryAgain line, is broken, I'd prefer if you tell me why it is broke then fix it for me, but if not that's fine.

Comment: I made a few changes after I tested it. It was broken because there was no label called `TryAgain:`.  I added that above the `val = inputBox(...` line.

Comment: Use the revised code, I think that should do it. Assuming you want the values put 122 columns to the right, and 5 rows down.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it doesn't let me type "SizeColor" I tried creating another Case, but I just keep getting it wrong.

Comment: typo. in the Case statment, make it say `Case "size", "sizecolor"` (all lower case).  That should fix it. My bad!!

Comment: Oh, fail on my behalf you did mention case sensitive :P

Comment: Ps, that paste "Size" for 122 cells.

Comment: Thanks for your help, all fixed and in working order